# Is it true that "for" indicates the whole duration of a verb? What about "he was ill for 3 days"?

Tags: grammar

Is it true that **for** indicates the whole duration of a verb?

What about the following?

> He was ill **for** three days when I turned back from my journey.

Comment: Is this for a test?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What you are asking is little unclear. Could you please specify what did you mean? And also, isn't **turn** in your example - *"...when I turn back from my journey"* - supposed to be in past tense?

Comment: thanks for your welcoming. there are lots of things to be corrected in my question, one of them as you expressed tense of the turn.  the situation I want to express is that I came in the middle of the whole situation of his being ill, let say the actual duration of his state of being ill was more than 4 days, but when I had turn back from my jurney it was on its 3th day. does `for` together with `was` imply this situation. In other words, does my sentence imply `he was in his third day of being ill when I turned back from my journey`? Sorry for giving you headache, I`m a self-learner.

Comment: It is totally fine to sometimes give someone a headache or to be a self-learner, don't worry! First thing we need to know that **to be ill** expresses state, and, thus, functions as a stative (or state) verb, which are not used in continuous tenses. You can either use the **Past Perfect** or **Past Simpe** in your sentence. I'll post an answer.

Comment: upd: well, an answer from Peter Shor is better. I'm giving up.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the word *for* that you need to correct here, it's the verb tense.

What you want to say is that you turned back after the third day of his illness, and when he had not yet recovered. In this case, you should say:

> He had been ill for three days when I turned back from my journey.

Grammatically, this doesn't necessarily mean that he had not yet recovered, but the context implies it.

The sentence

> He was ill for three days when I turned back from my journey,

is very unlikely to be spoken by a native English speaker. What it seems to mean is that he was ill for three days during or after the time you turned back. A similar sentence that a native English speaker might use is:

> He was ill for three days when he ate the clams at the Dirty Diner.